# Pokemon defending gyms

Tags: pokemon-go

I have been looking through the Pokemon Go questions and keep noticing questions about the coins you get for having a Pokemon in a gym. I recently had a Pokemon in a gym for 3+ days and I only got 50 coins.

Have they capped the coins at 50? 
Am I missing something? 
Have they changed how it works now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maximum coins you can obtain by day is 50. So your pokemon will never gave you after defending gym more then 50 coins because it is your daily limit.